# Parsing JSON information using AJAX into HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I am constructing a mongoDB database and I am trying to parse user information from a JSON format and insert it into HMTL code to be displayed.

It is currently not working and is not throwing off any errors.

Here is the current AJAX command:

```
var $userList = $('#userList');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: '127.0.0.1:3000/usersjson',
    success: function(userList) {
        $.each(userList, function(i, user) {
            $userList.append('<li>Name: '+ user.name +'</li>');
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error))
    },
});
```

Here is the JSON code I am trying to grab at 127.0.0.1:3000/usersjson:

```
[{
    _id: "54dcbe726ca6812a0d64a1be",
    name: "Hayden",
    __v: 0
},
{
    _id: "54dcbe856ca6812a0d64a1bf",
    name: "Chelsea",
    __v: 0
},
{
    _id: "54dcbe8c6ca6812a0d64a1c0",
    name: "Johan",
    __v: 0
}]
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Have you checked that you were indeed getting the piece of JSON you were expecting ? If not, print `userList` into the console and sse if that's what you expect.

Comment: The javascript console shows nothing.

Comment: I put in an alert(userlist) and and no alert is triggering.

`$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: '127.0.0.1:3000/usersjson',
  success: function(userList) {
   alert(userlist)
   $.each(userList, function(i, user) {
    $userList.append('<li>Name: '+ user.name +'</li>');
   });
  },
  error: function(error) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(error))
  },
 });`

Comment: you have a typo at `userlist`, which should be `userList`

Comment: I noticed and fixed that. Still shows nothing.

Comment: This should work just fine. Make sure that the request actually goes through to your server and that your server actually returns some JSON. My guess is that the request isn't even fired.

Comment: If the alert is not triggering i'm guessing the request is not firing. How would i go about resolving this?

Comment: Stop guessing if the request is firing or not and look at the Net tab of your developer tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue. I was getting an xmlHTTPrequest error and I thought it was an issue with the AJAX code but I decided to look into it and hanging my head against a wall for a couple hours. What that revealed was that I was missing the cross orgin access header on my http page.

Put the header in there and it works just fine.